# Is it possible to output Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis to a sonos?

Tags: c#, uwp, sonos

I have been developing an AI and it now talks but when using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis which outputs to the speakers on my computer. Is there a way that I could change the output to a remote sonos speaker on the network?

It would be great if there were but I fear that its probably not possible.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jishi/node-sonos-http-api. That supports a number of speech synthesis engines on Sonos speakers. Maybe you can use that or figure out how to do the same from your code.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that.

Comment: this looks promising also: https://www.howtogeek.com/292842/how-to-stream-any-audio-from-your-pc-to-a-sonos-player/